# Why doesn't numpy array support chainable operation and any suggestions to improve?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pycharm, method-chaining

What I mean by a chainable operation is that the chainable operation can use the latest dataframe created by previous operations. For example, consider the following:

```
array.ChainableOpA().ChainableOpB().ChainableOpC()
```

In this way, we can keep doing things "continually" and more clearly. Such design is provided in `pandas`.

`numpy` has many fucntions that are not "methods" of `ndarray` class. For example, you can call `numpy.nanmean` but there is no `array.nanmean`. This kind of design in numpy prohibits chainable operations.

1) So why would this happen? Is it due to performance issues or some zens of numpy?

2)And do we have a solution for this? I can think of subclassing `ndarray` and supplying the methods you want but seems tedious. And I found after you subclassing `ndarray`, the IDE I used, PyCharm, cannot recognize it as an array for displaying in SciView.

Comment: you are referring to a *fluent interface*. whether or not to support such an interface is up to the designers of the library. Indeed, the Python language itself and the buitl-in types tend to not support fluent interfaces, especially with mutable types.

Comment: Your premise that `obj.met_a().met_b().met_c()` is more readable than `fun_c(fun_b(fun_a(obj)))` is not self-evident, at least to me. The question seems thus primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Have you studied the `numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py` where a dozen `nan` functions are defined?  Evidently who ever wrote that file some years ago decided it was easier to use the function format than the method one.  I suppose you could try to rewrite it as methods, but don't expect a lot of help from other developers.  Look at release notes to see where the current develop effort is going (my impression is that `ufunc` are getting the most attention).